# How to save data to Firebase for currently logged in user?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created register users in my application. Now I want to save data in Firebase. I have method

```
func saveData() {
        ref = Database.database().reference().child(monthLabel.text!)
        let key = ref.childByAutoId().key
        let workDay = ["id": key,
                       "day": dayLabel.text! as String]

        ref.child(dayLabel.text!).setValue(workDay)
    }
```

No matter how user is currently logged in, values are saving into the same database. How to create different database for each user?

Comment: Don't create a different database for each user.  That's not going to scale.  You can use the user's UID along with security rules to create parts of the database that only the user can access.

Comment: @DougStevenson ok thank you, I will try to solve my problem